# "Database is locked" error when creating view in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, view

I am running SQLite 3.7.9 on a Ubuntu virtual machine (VirtualBox). I have a db called "frequency" on which I am trying to create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS SELECT * FROM frequency;
```

On running this I get the error "Error:database is locked.". (The actual view I am trying to create is more complex, but even this simple one won't work).

From what I have read online, this error usually occurs either due to 1) concurrent access, which I do not think is happening here as the db file is on the cirtual machine, or 2) running a CREATE/DROP command when a SELECT command has not finished - I do not think I am doing this either since my query is so basic.

I have also verified from ls -l that I have read-write permissions for both the file and the directory holding it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: may be this will help you http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/database-is-locked-with-create-td67109.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try listing all the processes you have running, make sure you don't have two database processes running at once.  Although the conditions were different, with me running a Windows VM, this fixed it.

Comment: This worked, I had another shell open where another instance of sqlite was running. Thanks!